# Node.js -- CSRF Token not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, csrf

I've been struggling with implementing CSRF token generation, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

server.js:

```
// set up ======================================================================
var express  = require('express');
var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var fs      = require('fs');
var csrf = require('csurf');
.
.
.

var app = express();
app.use(csrf());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.token = req.csrfToken();
    next();
});
.
.
.
```

login.ejs:

```
<form action="/login" method="post">
    <!--form fields-->
</form>
.
.
.
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= token %>">
```

When I try to open the login page, I get the following in the node.js console:

```
token is not defined
.
.
.
GET /login 500 93ms - 1.64kb
\
```

EDIT: server.js now looks like this:

```
var express  = require('express');
var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var fs      = require('fs');
var csrf = require('csurf');
.
.
.
var app = express();
require('./config/express')(app, __dirname);
require('./config/routes')(app);
app.use(csrf());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.token = req.csrfToken();
    next();
});
```

The login page loads now, but the CSRF token is undefined.

Comment: Shouldn't your input field be inside your form?

Comment: Yeah, that was a bit of an oversight on my part. I'm still getting the same error after that fix, though.

Comment: Do your `app.use()` statements you've shown come before all routes? It seems like your `/login` route(s) are before the two middlewares.

Comment: Moving app.use() statements after the routes allows the login page to load, but now the csrf token is undefined.

Comment: No, those `app.use()` lines definitely need to come *before* your routes. Otherwise `token` definitely won't be defined for the view. If you're getting the same error even with the lines before your routes, then `res.locals` must be getting overwritten somewhere after those middlewares.

Comment: Ah, I see. I put the app.use() lines before the routes, and successfully generated the CSRF token. How do I make sure the CSRF protection actually works when a CSRF attack is attempted?

Answer (score 1):

Your value in the form is wrong.

It should not just be

> value="<%= token %>"

but instead

> value="<%= csrfToken %>"

Answer (score 1):

try:

First install csurf module (https://github.com/expressjs/csurf):

```
$ npm install csurf
```

in server.js

```
var router = express.Router();
var csrf = require('csurf');

var csrfProtection = csrf();
router.use(csrfProtection);

router.get('/user/login/', function(req, res, next){
    res.render('user/login', {csrfToken: req.csrfToken()});
});
```

in login.ejs:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken >">
```

// you needed the =